# How to get the margin depends on two points in a rectangle?

Tags: c++, algorithm, visual-c++

Guys, I have two points(A, B) in a rectangle, now I want to get the margin of inside dash line rectangle relative to the outside rectangle

[image]

I just draw the one case in the illustrate, but there are so many cases in the actual situation.

Anyone can give me a C++ code snippet to cover all of the case?

Thanks you very much

Comment: You should know by now that's not how stackoverflow.com works. Please show us what you have tried, and tell us what problems you have with that code.

Comment: That's all just very basic geometry math.

Answer (score 0):

The margins is

```
int LeftMargin = Min(x1, x2);
int RightMargin = Width - Max(x1, x2);
int TopMargin = Min(y1, y2);
int BottomMargin = Height - Max(y1, y2);
```